# How to Spring Inject My Controller layer from Groovy

Tags: java, spring, groovy, mybatis

I'm trying to learn groovy and integrating it with an existing Java jar. The java code makes use of DI but i cant seem to get it to work from my groovy script.

The Java application contains a data access layer using Mybatis. This layer consists of a number of Interfaces (e.g IUser) and Controllers 
e.g.

```
@Service
public class UserController implements IUser
```

The Controllers make use of Mybatis Mapper Classes.

The whole thing is pulled together using Spring with default-autowire="byName">

Its set up to use annotations to access the mappers within the controllers.

Mybatis is configured in Spring to scan and inject the mappers

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
<property name="basePackage" value="com.directski.data.mapper" />
<property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

So when i run my application in java everything works normally. Including any mappers i have called using

```
@Autowired
private UserMapper userMapper;
```

When i try to include this jar as part of a groovy scrip i start to run into some problems. Im using the same applicationContext file for Spring

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("controller-layer-applicationContext.xml");
```

When i run as a script i can see from the logs that the components are scanned. Some of my controllers include a @PostConstruct method which gets called, and database queries are sucessfully executed. However when trying to call my controllers from my script i get null pointer errors.

I have tried using @Autowired to create my controllers in groovy but they dont seem to get injected. I have also implemented factory.registerBeanDefinition() as per examples in http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Spring+Factories+with+Groovy
however this does seem to get my controller to be created, but the Mybatis Mappers within my controllers are returning null

How can i make sure my controllers are autowired correctly from Groovy?

Comment: could you try fo force scan your components : new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(ctx).scan('') ctx.refresh()

Comment: Thats doesnt seem to have worked, Im stull playing around with it in various formats.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So i have something thats working. Taken from answer 5 [How to programmatically create bean definition with injected properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370161/how-to-programmatically-create-bean-definition-with-injected-properties)

```
public class AppContextExtendingBean implements ApplicationContextAware{


@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException{

    AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

    version1(beanFactory);

    }


    private void version1(AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory){
    IUser userController= (UserController) beanFactory.createBean(UserController,AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
    beanFactory.initializeBean(userController, "user");

    User testuser = userController.getUser(3);


    }


}


ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("controller-layer-applicationContext.xml");

AppContextExtendingBean bean = new AppContextExtendingBean();

bean.setApplicationContext(ctx);
```