# Programmatically adding a Listener to a Spring application?

Tags: java, xml, spring, session, listener

I'm following [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/) to set up a `HttpSessionListener` for my Spring app. Unfortunately, I'm not able to modify any of the XML files, so my problem is the following line:

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>com.mkyong.SessionCounterListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Is there any way to add the listener programmatically without modifying any XML file? And if so, how and where to do it?

Comment: Are you using Servlet 3.0?

Comment: why u couldnt modify your xml file?what error you are getting while doing it?

Comment: Actually, I'm just modifying a project that was given to me, so @SotiriosDelimanolis, I actually don't know. How to find out?

Comment: Check the `<web-app>` element's `version` attribute.

Comment: @Kamlesh Arya: Because there is no XML file and I have no idea why.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis same problem here, the project doesn't have any XML files except for a file named `pom.xml`.

Comment: check your src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder ,web.xml file should be there

Comment: @KamleshArya: nope, there's just `templates` and `resources`, no `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370161/how-to-programmatically-create-bean-definition-with-injected-properties